# How to open a Client app through a browser? like Secondlife.com does it to open second life client

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to write and application on windows where my application shud be prompted to open thru a browser link. how can I do that?

Comment: Are you referring to ClickOnce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about second life, but I would [register an file extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166549.aspx) (like `.MyApplication`) with my application and create links to a `.MyApplication`-file on the web site. You an also encode special startup parameters inside that little file.